# Reading excel table into dataframe and spliting values into lists

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file containing some columns and, in each column some values to be searched into a database.

[image: example table]

I want to read this file (I am using pandas because its a very simple way to read excel files) and extract info into variables:

```
Desired extract information of each row
Company : Ebay (STR format)
company_name_for_search : [EBAY, eBay, Ebay] (list of strings)
company_register: [4722,4721] (list os ints)
```

Getting this info, I will run a search script. Some info must be lists because the script will do e search for every item inside the list (for loop).

When I read the excel file, each column is read as a object type in a dataframe, so I couldn't access each value inside such object.

How to split values, change formats and deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are represented as single strings rather than rows of strings and numbers.

Instead of:

| company_name | register |
| --- | --- |
| eBay | 4722 |
| eBay | 4721 |
| Amazon | 9999 |

You have:

| company_name | register |
| --- | --- |
| ebay,ebay | 4722,4721 |
| amazon | 9999 |

You can [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) each string and then [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the resulting Series containing arrays to get a long form DataFrame.

```py
import pandas as pd

mess = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "letters": ["A,B", "C,D", "E,F,G,H"],
        "nums": ["100,200", "300,400", "500, 600, 700, 800"],
    }
)

mess = mess.apply(lambda col: col.str.split(",").explode())
```

Comment: I did not get something. I am trying to apply you code but I got two issues : 
1) "FutureWarning: reindexing with a non-unique Index is deprecated and will raise in a future version.
  mess = dfbase.apply(lambda col: col.str.split(",").explode())"
and 2) ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

Comment: What version of pandas are you using @FábioRB? I haven't received that warning on version 1.4.3. You can check by printing `pd.__version__`.

Comment: 1.4.3.
I think that I got the issue. You said an example where the number os itens in each group are compatible. I have some as I showed in the example (1 at first column, 1 or more at the second an third)